# How can stop foreach an div class in smarty2 template

Tags: foreach, smarty, break, smarty2

This is my code and I need stop foreach the last ul and tab-content permanently I use a smarty 2 I have try everything and I can not resolve it.

```
<div class="tabs">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    {foreach from=$languages item=v}
       <li>
          <a href="#tab_1">Example</a>
       </li>

   //  --> I Want stop this two

    <ul>
    <div class="tab-content">

   // I Want stop this two <---

       <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_1">
           <p>Example text</p>
       </div>
    </div>
   {/foreach}
</div>
```

I Have try this but is not working

```
{$data = [1,2,3,4,5]}
  {foreach $data as $value}
    {if $value == 3}
      {* abort iterating the array *}
          {break}
    {/if}
    {$value}
  {/foreach}
  {*
    prints: 1 2
  *}
```

Comment: There's no official way to break a smarty foreach. If you need to, you're using smarty in the wrong way

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is to simple assign selected data in PHP (in your example not 5 elements but 2 elements) to Smarty and simple display data in Smarty

Smarty template file:

```
{foreach from=$data item=value}
  {$value}
{/foreach}
```

And in PHP file not:

```
$smarty->assign('data',array(1,2,3,4,5));
```

but

```
$smarty->assign('data',array(1,2));
```

However if you cannot change assigned data from PHP (or it comes from other system) you can simple loop for all elements but display only for example 2 first as below:

```
  {foreach from=$data item=value name=data}
      {if $smarty.foreach.data.iteration le 2}
        {$value}
      {/if}
  {/foreach}
```

Comment: {if $smarty.foreach.data.iteration === 1}{/if}